# Incorrect string value: '\xF2\xB8\x80\xA0\xE6\x88...'

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, encoding, utf-8

There's a lot of similar questions on Google.
But this one is different.

This issue is from the product server.
There are hundreds of data will be inserted/updated to this table in a second.
And this error happens randomly.
The database encoding is utf8, the collation is utf8_general_ci.

First, I tried to print every title before it was inserted to the database.
But there's no any emoji in these titles.
I also tried to insert the same title again but nothing happened.

Second, I changed to check the byte length before it was inserted to the database.

```
String title = articleDataForm.getTitle();
int length = title.length();

for( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ){
    if( StringUtils.mid(title, i, 1).getBytes().length > 3 ){
        logger.info("Title = " + articleDataForm.getTitle());
    }
}
```

But nothing was printed out. So there's no any 4 bytes character.

Here are the error messages.

```
2020-05-27 11:16:06 [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper]-[WARN] SQL Error: 1366, SQLState: HY000
2020-05-27 11:16:06 [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper]-[ERROR] Incorrect string value: '\xF2\xB8\x80\xA0\xE6\x88...' for column 'title' at row 1
2020-05-27 11:16:06 [org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl]-[ERROR] HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement]
2020-05-27 11:16:06 [mvc.controller.exception.resolver.Log4jExceptionResolver]-[ERROR] org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:351) ~[spring-orm-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253) ~[spring-orm-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:536) ~[spring-orm-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746) ~[spring-tx-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714) ~[spring-tx-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:533) ~[spring-tx-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:304) ~[spring-tx-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy66.insertOrUpdate(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at mvc.controller.service.v3.HotTopicsPutController.put(HotTopicsPutController.java:95) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor122.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [catalina.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71) [log4j-web-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [catalina.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [catalina.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522) [catalina.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [catalina.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620) [catalina.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [catalina.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_101]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3217) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3090) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3491) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:600) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:474) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1437) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:494) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3245) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2451) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:156) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:532) ~[spring-orm-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF2\xB8\x80\xA0\xE6\x88...' for column 'title' at row 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:695) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:663) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:653) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:115) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2041) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1827) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2041) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1977) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:4963) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1962) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:384) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3217) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3090) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3491) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:600) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:474) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1437) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:494) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3245) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2451) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:156) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:532) ~[spring-orm-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    ... 54 more
```

Comment: Your call to `String.getBytes` should specify a character encoding. Otherwise, you'll get whatever the JVM's default encoding is, which is often not UTF-8.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I've changed it to `getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` before I deployed to my server. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *trying* to be a four-byte UTF8 character, but it does not map to any valid UTF8 encoding.

In UTF8, if the first nibble is `F` (or `1111` in binary) then it's always a four-byte UTF8 character.

This is from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 which explains UTF8 in more detail:
[image]

The bytes you showed, F2 B8 80 A0 look like they might be valid given this pattern.

```
11110010 10111000 10000000 10100000
```

But not *all* bytes beginning with `F` map to valid UTF8 encodings. For example, there's a large gap between `F0B18D8A` and `F3A08081`. Perhaps someday a future revision to UTF8 will use encodings where the first byte is `F1` or `F2`, but currently that range is not in use.

http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm?start=126275 shows the gap between the last CJK character and the first of the series of Tag characters:

[image]

So the bytes that caused the error aren't a valid UTF8 encoding.

Likewise, if you enter your string of hex bytes into any UTF8 decoder, it won't recognize it as a valid encoding.

http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=F2B880A0&mode=bytes returns this:

[image]

I think the most likely explanation is that the source of your input data isn't encoding it in UTF8 at all. It could be another character encoding, or it could be binary data that isn't in any text encoding.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found the problem string by `Utility.bytesToHex(title.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).contains("F2B880A0E688")`.

Comment: @KimiChiu - You found the string.  But did you figure out what caused the bad string?

Comment: @RickJames Yes, I figured it out. There's a user edited the title of the article. it's two Chinese word which is combined as one word. I don't know how he did it. It looks like this one. https://i.imgur.com/zRqEYi8.png

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 is 3 bytes in MySQL. You should use utf8mb4 which covers full Unicode with it's 4 bytes.

See [Unicode Character Sets](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html) in the documentation.

Comment: I already read these references before I post this question. You can see I tried to check the bytes length before I inserted it in my Question. There's no any 4 bytes length character over there.